# External CSS won't import/load, suddenly?

Tags: html, css

All of a sudden, my stylesheet won't import/link (sorry for lack of appropriate terms) on a site i manage.

Here is the code .... am tearing my hear out - any tips???

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML><html><head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; utf-8">



<head>
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Cantarell&subset=latin' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<title>Who Makes My Wine?</title>
<link href="styles/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<script type="text/javascript">

  var _gaq = _gaq || [];
  _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-16645738-4']);
  _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

  (function() {
    var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
  })();

</script>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width"> 
</head>
```

Comment: Not sure if this will help, but check the location of styles.css - that it wasn't moved or name changed - and you have 2 starting `<head>` tags - remove the second one.

Comment: i would imagine you should be getting some sort of browser console error

Comment: hi there - i deleted the second <head> tag - thank you. Still having the problem though. argh. FYI full page is here http://whomakesmywine.com.au/

Comment: Can you show the directory from the parent folder?

Comment: screen grab here from coda, in dropbox https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/7875616/Screen%20Shot%202015-04-01%20at%2012.23.52%20pm.png

Comment: Check your css I saw some excessive `;` in `h2`, `h3`

Comment: This probably won't make a difference but may help clean up your code: You close some self closing tags with a `/` and others you don't. You are using HTML5 so no big deal but who really wants inconsistent code?

Comment: yep a lot of lapses in your css code dude I saw a ton of it :)

Comment: hi everyone YES I agree on all of the above (i'm a designer and a VERY novice coder!) fixed all the issues noted (aside from tidying up, i will get to that) but i'm still having the same problem, but only on this page http://whomakesmywine.com.au/   (the index.html)  It's driving me loco!!!   all other pages have same <head> but the index.html won't work??

Answer (score 1):

I saw your error find this and remove the i `margin: 0;i` and everything will work fine. You can find it at the very beginning. cheers :)

Comment: Yeah. That has to be it.

Comment: thanks guys :) i fixed that in the css file but still having problems :(

Comment: doesn't solve your problem? when you remove the "i" ?